# How to change array key number to specific name using loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im new in PHP, please see the example below

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => Array 
  ( 
    [fee_id] => 15 
    [fee_amount] => 308.5 
    [year] => 2009 
  ) 

  [1] => Array 
  ( 
    [fee_id] => 14 
    [fee_amount] => 308.5 
    [year] => 2009 
  ) 

)
```

Change to something like.

```
Array 
( 
  "Data: 0" => Array 
  ( 
    [fee_id] => 15 
    [fee_amount] => 308.5 
    [year] => 2009 
  ) 

  "Data: 1" => Array 
  ( 
    [fee_id] => 14 
    [fee_amount] => 308.5 
    [year] => 2009 
  ) 

)
```

I trying to create a for loop function traverse the array like this

```
$new = [];
    
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $new['Data'][] = $value;    
}
```

The code above is wrapped in the "Data" array which is incorrect.

Comment: That is not possible, you can not have the same key on the same level multiple times.

Comment: And when you request `array['Data']` for your expected array - what should be returned? First subarray, second, third or which one?

Comment: Not possible to give the same key on an array on the same level, you can use a simple auto index of array `$new[] = $value;` instead, that's enough.

Comment: @CBroe I have edited the expected result to different key since it cant be same key

Comment: @u_mulder Basically I just want to remain the $value but replace the $key from number to specific String

Comment: @kupendra Noted...i have edited the expected result

Comment: Create an array that contains the text elements `Data: 0`, `Data: 1` etc. (dynamically, with a loop, based on how many items your input array contains), and then use `array_combine`. (Or loop over the input array, create the appropriate key for the current item, and then assign it to a new result array under that key.)

Comment: (The second version would be as simple as `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { $new['Data: '.$key] = $value; }`)

Comment: The second example seems less usable than the first. Are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this it may helpful for you.

```
$arr = [

    0 => [
        'test' => 'value'
    ],
    1 => [
        'test' => 'value'
    ],
    2 => [
        'test' => 'value'
    ]

];
echo "<pre>arr: ";
print_r($arr);
$newArr = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $row){
    $newArr["Data: ".$key] = $row;
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $new['Data:' . $key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) it will help you.

```
$input_array = [
 [
  'fee_id' => 15,
  'fee_amount' => 308.5, 
  'year' => 2009 
 ],
 [
  'fee_id' => 14,
  'fee_amount' => 308.5 ,
  'year' => 2009,
 ]
];

$output_array = array_combine(
 array_map(function($key){ return 'Data: '.$key; }, array_keys($input_array)),
 $input_array
);
print_r($output_array);
```

[working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0d427696ba927276a3919c30dabd3e2f2cf7f73)

Answer (score 0):

Solution if the key in the array $input itself should be changed and no new array should be created.

```
$input = [
 ['fee_id' => 15,'fee_amount' => 308.5, 'year' => 2009],
 ['fee_id' => 14,'fee_amount' => 308.5 ,'year' => 2009]
];

$keyPrefix = 'Data: ';

foreach($input as $key => $value){
  unset($input[$key]);
  $input[$keyPrefix.$key] = $value;
}
```